# Is it possible for a type to have alignment requirements other than 'n-byte alignment'

Tags: c++, memory-alignment

For example, consider the following:

Assume that int is 4-byte aligned, and long is 8-byte aligned.

```
struct example
{
    int a;
    long b;
    int c;
};
```

the obvious way for the compiler to lay this out in memory would be:
AAAAPPPPBBBBBBBBCCCCPPPP with the whole structure having an 8-byte alignment.

- P refers to a byte of padding
- A refers to a byte of a
- B refers to a byte of b
- C refers to a byte of c

In this case, sizeof(example) is 24.

but another way of doing it would be the following:
AAAABBBBBBBBCCCC with the whole structure having alignment such that the address of the starting byte mod 8 = 4 (not sure how to say this more succinctly)

in this case, there is no padding needed, so you save 8 bytes per instance.

My question is, are compilers allowed to do this(by the standard)? Do they actually do this? I've always seen alignment discussed simply in bytes.

Comment: Standard-layout structs *may not have padding at their beginning*, see [class.mem]/19. One reason is that it allows converting a pointer to the struct to a pointer to its first member.

Comment: Your second version doesn't work, the long isn't guaranteed to be 8-byte aligned.

Comment: g++4.8.1 packs it as `AAAA PPPP BBBB BBBB CCCC PPPP`. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0de698917010f544)

Comment: @Mat That's the core of the OP's question - whether the structure's alignment requirement can be "must be aligned at *second half of 8-byte word.*"

Comment: Memory alignment rules are CPU specific.

Comment: @DyP Yes you're right, I've changed it, but it doesn't impact the question really.

Comment: @hvd There would be no padding between array elements.

Comment: @Bwmat You're right, I've misread what you're suggesting. Something that *would* be a problem is getting memory allocation functions to return a suitably aligned pointer though. They know nothing of the type they're allocating for. Another problem would be putting your struct in a union alongside a `long`. The union type would have alignment requirements 8+0 and 8+4 simultaneously.

Comment: @hvd Yeah, I think that the union issue would disallow this, as well as the fact that the standard guarantees that the result of new char[X] is suitably aligned for any type, which cannot be the case if this were allowed. I wonder if it's mentioned anywhere explicitly in the standard though, and not just a consequence of these rules.

Comment: Alignment is implementation-specific. When I use gcc to build for a 16-bit target (Microchip), the default alignment is 2 bytes, so there would be no padding in your example. You could try using the `__attribute__((packed))` attribute. It may be that your 8-byte alignment is to improve performance rather than being a hardware limitation. For example, on 16-bit Microchip controllers, odd addresses cause an address fault, so a struct with several char's will always have padding bytes to align the char's on even addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A struct cannot have alignment requirements that are less strict than the alignment requirements of its members.  If a member of the struct is 8-byte aligned, then the struct needs to be at least 8-byte aligned.  If the struct is 8-byte aligned, then in your example, the second member would not be 8-byte aligned, since it is offset four bytes from the beginning of an 8-byte aligned struct, so it wouldn't meet the requirements.

The possible alternative would be to put padding at the beginning of the struct, but this is not allowed:

C++03 9.2p17

> A pointer to a POD-struct object, suitably converted using a `reinterpret_cast`, points to its initial member (...) and vice-versa.  [Note: There might therefore be unnamed padding within a POD-struct object, but not at its beginning, as necessary to achieve proper alignment.]

Another possible alternative would be (as your are suggesting) to have the 8-byte alignment actually mean (`(address%8)==4)` (as opposed to `(address%8)==0`).  If that were the case though, then your 8-byte aligned `long` would have the same requirement.  It isn't possible to have types with both `(address%8)==0` and `(address%8)==4` alignment, since there would be no way to generically allocate memory that meets both alignment requirements.  Since the `long` would have this special alignment requirement as well, you still wouldn't be able to avoid the padding.

Comment: You've misunderstood, the struct would _not_ be 8-byte aligned. It would be 4-bytes offset from an 8-byte alignment.

Comment: @Bwmat: A struct cannot have alignment requirements that are less strict than the alignment requirements of its members.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this requirement is less strict. It's as strict, just offset. In any case, could anyone quote the standard on this?

Comment: @Bwmat: I see what you are saying. I've added more to my answer which hopefully addresses this.

Answer (score 2):

You are forgetting about arrays. In general case, how do you propose the compiler should make sure that "starting byte mod 8 = 4" in case of an array, for each array element?

Remember that C language requires that for any array object of type `T a[N]` the following holds true

```
sizeof a == sizeof *a * N
```

That means that any padding present inside the entire array object `a` must come from individual elements of type `T`. Arrays are not allowed to add their own padding.

In other words, the compiler cannot simply remember to align the individual struct objects properly. It actually has to include the padding into the struct objects and count that padding as part of `sizeof` for that struct object.

Your `AAAABBBBBBBBCCCC` is a "nice" one, since when such objects are stored compactly in an array (with no extra padding), they all end up properly aligned if the very first element of the array is properly aligned. But how do you expect to achieve proper alignment for the first element if the array memory is allocated by `malloc`, for example. `malloc` knows nothing about the type for which memory is being allocated, which means that it can't tailor its behavior to specific alignment requirements of your type.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler will try to align each members, by adding padding. There is usually a maximum alignment that depends on the compiler and the processor (for example usually you don't have alignments like 256 bytes alignment). This maximum alignment is not even present in the standard, so it is not impossible to have a compiler aligning structs of size 2048...

As said by DyP in the comments, gcc can pack it as:

```
AAAA PPPP BBBB BBBB CCCC PPPP
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0de698917010f544).

Please note that it can pack it another way (try it with `double` on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/YDH5lD) and compare with [Stacked-Crooked](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cf33fecab0327c6)).

If you want no padding, you can use a preprocessor directive:

```
#pragma pack
```

This is compatible with [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html) and [MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx).

With this, the same version of gcc used for the previous example packs it as:

```
AAAA BBBB BBBB CCCC
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a4b32b9ea41ac0f).